# Definition of leading log terms in one loop corrections for gravity

Tags: quantum-field-theory, operators, quantum-gravity

One loop corrections for gravity usually includes non-local terms in the action such as $R\log(\frac{-\Box}{\mu^2})R$, where $\Box=g^{\mu\nu}\nabla_\mu\nabla_\nu$ is the D'Alembert operator, $R$ is the scalar curvature and $\mu$ is just some constant. My problem concerns how to interpret the log of an operator. In http://arxiv.org/pdf/1507.07829.pdf, the definition goes like (see equation 4.2 in pg 9)

$
\log(\frac{-\Box}{\mu^2})=\int_0^\infty ds \left(\frac{1}{\mu^2+s}+\frac{1}{-\Box+s}\right).
$

Besides this definition be quite arbitrary to me, again a function of $\Box$ shows up and I end up with the same problem. So how should I interpret a function like $f(\Box)$? Is it to be seen as a Taylor expansion in the same way that is usually defined in quantum mechanics, i.e.

$
f(\Box)=\sum_n\frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}\Box^n \quad?
$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To promote a function $f(x)$ of a number to a function of a linear operator $f(A)$, one way to proceed is to diagonalize the operator $A = V^{-1} D V$ where $D$ is diagonal.  We then let $f$ act on each of the eigenvalues (i.e. the diagonal entries of $D$) and define $f(A)$ to be
$$
f(A) \equiv V^{-1} f(D) V.
$$
Of course if $A$ is not diagonalizable, then things can be trickier.  The Wikipedia entry for the [log of a matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm_of_a_matrix) discusses how to first put the operator in Jordan normal form and then how the Taylor series of $\log(I+K)$ naturally truncates for each Jordan block.  Hopefully your $\Box$ operator is diagonalizable with your choice of boundary conditions.

One nice aspect of your redefinition of the $\log$ is that if $\Box = A + \delta A$, where $A$ might be easy to diagonalize but $A+\delta A$ not so much and where $[A, \delta A] \neq 0$, then your formula provides a nice rewriting of the logarithm that does not involve messy details of [Baker-Campbell-Hausdorff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you know any other reference for all of this besides wikipedia? I need to see this in more detail. It would be great to see the Lie theory    perspective for this. Which lie group does the operator box benlong to?

Comment: I would have thought it's only natural to associate $\Box$ to a Lie group when the manifold is a symmetric space or a coset space.  In this case, $\Box$ should be related to the Casimirs of the associated simple Lie groups.  (I love Wikipedia, but I would guess a vanilla book on linear algebra might be useful.  For symmetric spaces, there is an ancient tome by Helgason.)